# Edges of an object move about while rotating

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I have a project featuring a 3d object. The user can rotate and zoom it in/out with finger gestures. The problem I have is while rotating a cube (other solids also cause the same error, but I'll set an example on cube), the edges of it kind of disintegrate (as shown in screenshots). The faster the rotation is the more substantial the problem becomes.

I tried to mask it by disable face culling, so that the user sees the inside of the cube, which basically has the same colour. However the project manager isn't pleased with that solution (I admitt it doesn't work that well).

The cube has 6 faces, each containing about 242 polygons.

#### Here are the code snippets relevant to rendering the 3d sceene (I'm using VBO):

```java
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) 
{
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    isBlendingEnabled = false;

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, mEyeX, mEyeY, mEyeZ, mLookX, mLookY, mLookZ, mUpX, mUpY, mUpZ);


    if(!mSolid.equals(((ActivityMain) mContext).getSolid())){
        refreshSolid();
        refreshTextureData();
    }

    if(mSolid.hasChanged){
        refreshSolid();
    }

    if(mSolid.hasTexturesChanged){
        refreshTextureData();
        mSolid.hasTexturesChanged = false;
    }

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);                    

    // Set per-vertex lighting program.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);

    // Set program handles for solid drawing.
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVMatrix"); 
    mLightPosHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_LightPos");
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Color");
    mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_Texture");
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position");        
    mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Normal"); 
    mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");                        

    // Calculate position of the light. Handle it's rotation
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mLightModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mLightModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);      
    Matrix.rotateM(mLightModelMatrix, 0, mAngleInDegrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.translateM(mLightModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 3.5f);

    Matrix.multiplyMV(mLightPosInWorldSpace, 0, mLightModelMatrix, 0, mLightPosInModelSpace, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(mLightPosInEyeSpace, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mLightPosInWorldSpace, 0);                        

    //Doing that step for each of the faces
    for(int i = 0; i < mSolid.get3dMesh().size(); i++){
        // Draw a solid.
        // Translate the solid into the screen.

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -3.5f);

        // Set a matrix that contains the current rotation.
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mCurrentRotation, 0);        
        Matrix.rotateM(mCurrentRotation, 0, mDeltaX, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Matrix.rotateM(mCurrentRotation, 0, mDeltaY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        //handle inertia
        if(Math.abs(mDeltaX) > 2f){
            mDeltaX = Math.signum(mDeltaX);
            mDeltaX = 0.5f*mDeltaX;
        }else if(Math.abs(mDeltaX) > 0.05f){
            mDeltaX = 0.99f*mDeltaX;
        }else
            mDeltaX = 0.0f;

        if(Math.abs(mDeltaY) > 2f){
            mDeltaY = Math.signum(mDeltaY);
            mDeltaY = 0.5f*mDeltaY;
        }else if(Math.abs(mDeltaY) > 0.05f){
            mDeltaY = 0.99f*mDeltaY;
        }else
            mDeltaY = 0.0f;

        // Multiply the current rotation by the accumulated rotation, and then set the accumulated rotation to the result.
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mCurrentRotation, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0);
        System.arraycopy(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0, 16);

        // Rotate the cube taking the overall rotation into account.
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0);
        System.arraycopy(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0, 16);

        // Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        // Bind the texture to this unit.
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle[i]);

        // Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);

        drawCube(i);
    }
    if(ModelCorePrefs.getDrawMesh())
        drawVertices();

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc (GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);    
    isBlendingEnabled = true;

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, -3.5f, -3.5f);
    Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0, 2f, 1.0f, 2f);

    // Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    // Bind the texture to this unit.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle[mSolid.get3dMesh().size()]);

    // Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);

    drawShadow();
}
```

#### The drawCube() method used above:

```java
private void drawCube(int i)
{   
    // Pass in the position information
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mCubePositionsBufferIdx[i]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);                       
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Pass in the color information
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mCubeColorsBufferIdx[i]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, mColorDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Pass in the normal information
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mCubeNormalsBufferIdx[i]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);                
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalHandle, mNormalDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Pass in the texture coordinate information
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mCubeTexCoordsBufferIdx[i]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which currently contains model * view).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);   

    // Pass in the modelview matrix.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);                

    // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which now contains model * view * projection).        
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    System.arraycopy(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, 16);

    // Pass in the combined matrix.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    // Pass in the light position in eye space.        
    GLES20.glUniform3f(mLightPosHandle, mLightPosInEyeSpace[0], mLightPosInEyeSpace[1], mLightPosInEyeSpace[2]);

    // Draw the cube.
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mSolid.get3dMesh().get(i).length/3);                               
}
```

#### And the screenshot of the problem:

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you remove the `glGet*Location (...)` calls from your `onDrawFrame (...)` method. Those things do not change after you link your program initially, and searching for those locations by string name each frame is going to hinder your performance. Likewise, you only have to set the sampler uniform once per-program since it is always using texture image unit 0.

#### As for your real issue:

I see no evidence that each face in your loop has its own unique model matrix, so you should move the logic that incrementally transforms the matrix out of the loop. Otherwise you are going to rotate each face in the cube individually, which is what your diagram is showing. To be honest, I do not know why you even have to draw the faces one at a time.

```
// Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
// ^^^^^ ONLY DO THAT ONCE!


// Translate the solid into the screen.
Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -3.5f);

// Set a matrix that contains the current rotation.
Matrix.setIdentityM(mCurrentRotation, 0);        
Matrix.rotateM(mCurrentRotation, 0, mDeltaX, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(mCurrentRotation, 0, mDeltaY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

//handle inertia
if(Math.abs(mDeltaX) > 2f){
    mDeltaX = Math.signum(mDeltaX);
    mDeltaX = 0.5f*mDeltaX;
}else if(Math.abs(mDeltaX) > 0.05f){
    mDeltaX = 0.99f*mDeltaX;
}else
    mDeltaX = 0.0f;

if(Math.abs(mDeltaY) > 2f){
    mDeltaY = Math.signum(mDeltaY);
    mDeltaY = 0.5f*mDeltaY;
}else if(Math.abs(mDeltaY) > 0.05f){
    mDeltaY = 0.99f*mDeltaY;
}else
    mDeltaY = 0.0f;

// Multiply the current rotation by the accumulated rotation, and then set the accumulated rotation to the result.
Matrix.multiplyMM(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mCurrentRotation, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0);
System.arraycopy(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0, 16);

// Rotate the cube taking the overall rotation into account.
Matrix.multiplyMM(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0);
System.arraycopy(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0, 16);

//Doing that step for each of the faces
for(int i = 0; i < mSolid.get3dMesh().size(); i++){
    // Draw a solid.

    // Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    // Bind the texture to this unit.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle[i]);

    drawCube(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed - moving the rotation outside the loop fixed the weird edges.

Thanks also for the tip - I'll bear it in mind next time I develop something on Android Opengl :)